# How do I get the location of the drawn circle created by graph.draw_circle in PySimpleGUI?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I want to create a slider with two sliding knobs using PySimpleGUI.
I decide to use the graph element to create two circles (knob 1 and knob 2) by dragging them. The slider element in PySimpleGUI does not support two knobs.

I modified the code based on this demo. https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Graph_Drawing_And_Dragging_Figures.py

My problem is, how do I get the location of the circle? Can I read the location value of the drawn circle (the center of the circle) directly rather than the mouse location?

Thank you.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.Graph(
            canvas_size=(400, 20),
            graph_bottom_left=(0, 0),
            graph_top_right=(800, 40),
            key="-GRAPH-",
            enable_events=True,
            drag_submits=True,
            motion_events=True,
            right_click_menu=[[''],['Erase item','Send to back']]
            )],
        [sg.Text(key='-INFO-', size=(60, 1))]]

window = sg.Window("Drawing and Moving Stuff Around", layout, finalize=True)

# get the graph element for ease of use later
graph = window["-GRAPH-"]
knob1 = graph.draw_circle((20, 20), 20, fill_color='red')
knob2 = graph.draw_circle((50, 20), 20, fill_color='blue')
dragging = False
start_point = end_point = prior_rect = None
crosshair_lines = []

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break  # exit
    if event == "-GRAPH-":  # if there's a "Graph" event, then it's a mouse
        x, y = values["-GRAPH-"]
        if not dragging:
            start_point = (x)
            dragging = True
            drag_figures = graph.get_figures_at_location((x,y))
            lastx = x
        else:
            end_point = (x)
        delta_x = x - lastx
        lastx = x
        circle_loc = 0
        if None not in (start_point, end_point):
            if end_point <= 800 and end_point >= 0:
                for fig in drag_figures:
                    graph.move_figure(fig, delta_x, 0)
                    graph.update()
        window["-INFO-"].update(value=f"mouse {values['-GRAPH-']}")
    elif event.endswith('+UP'):         # The drawing has ended because mouse up
        window["-INFO-"].update(value=f"grabbed rectangle from {start_point} to {end_point}")
        start_point, end_point = None, None  # enable grabbing a new rect
        dragging = False
        prior_rect = None
window.close()
```

Comment: You drew the circle, didn't you?  You can just remember the coordinates where you drew it.'

Comment: @TimRoberts The circle is move by the mouse after. The circle is the slider knob. I want to get the new location from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no method provided in PySimpleGUI to get any attribute of the item you drawn on the graph, tkinter code is required to get what you want if you need something special.

```py
def get_center(element, id_):
    """
    Return the coordinate of center for the circle id_ in the element.
    - args
        - element: The Graph element.
        - id_: id of the circle item drawn on Graph.
    - Return
        - (x0, y0): center of circle
    """
    # bbox in tkinter
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = element.widget.bbox(id_)
    # bbox in PySimpleGUI
    x3, y3 = element._convert_canvas_xy_to_xy(x1, y1)
    x4, y4 = element._convert_canvas_xy_to_xy(x2, y2)
    # Using operator '/' here to avoid calculation error
    return (x3+x4)/2, (y3+y4)/2
```

You can use it like

```py
            drag_figures = graph.get_figures_at_location((x,y))
            if drag_figures:
                # index 0 for botton one and -1 for top one in the figure list
                print(get_center(graph, drag_figures[-1]))
```